# Decomposition of $L^2(S^1)$

Tags: lie-groups, harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a compact abelian group. Then for any $\phi\in C(G)$ one can define an "action" on $L^2(G)$ via an integral operator $T_\phi$ as follows:
$$T_\phi(f)(h)=\int_G \phi(g) f(hg)\, dg$$

Let $R$ denote the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra of these operators. (It is not hard to see that $R$ is adjoint-closed, commutative, and consists of compact operators.)

**Proposition.** $L^2(G)=\widehat{\bigoplus}_{0\ne \mu\colon R\to\mathbb{C}} L^2(G)_{\mu}$ of simultaneous eigenspaces
$$L^2(G)_\mu=\{f\in L^2(G)\mid T_\phi f=\mu(T_\phi) f \text{ for all } T_\phi\in R\}$$

This is corollary 3.6.1 in Garrett's [notes](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/notes_2012-13/06c_cpt_ab_gps.pdf) (See page 7). (I believe there are some typos in the notes; I hope they are fixed above.)

Now, while I can follow the derivation of this proposition, I'm not sure how it can be applied to the simplest case namely $G=S^1$. In other words, what are $\mu$ and $L^2(S^1)_\mu$ explicitly? (By Corollary 4.0.1 in the same notes, I can say that each $L^2(S^1)_\mu$ can be decomposed into a direct sum of one dimensional spaces given by characters of $S^1$ or simply the exponential functions.)

Comment: The operators $T_\phi$ look like convolution operators with kernel $\phi$; not exactly, but virtually. Hence, the functions in $L^2(G)_\mu$ must be "simple", so that they are eigenvectors of all these operators, in case $G=S^1$ you get exponentials. You can write $\widehat{T_\phi (f)}(n)=m_\phi(n)\hat{f}(n)$ and then, for example, $\mu(T_\phi)=m_\phi(n)$; verify this is a functional. Here $L^2(S^1)_\mu= Ae^{inx}$.

Comment: To give you a point of view on the proposition, remember that in linear algebra a family of operators are simultaneously diagonalizable exactly when they commute. The convolutions form a family of commuting operators, so you try to get a common diagonalization.

Comment: @user90189: your comments seem to be a perfectly good answer; why not type it in the answer box? The question is what are $\mu$ and $L^2(S^1)_\mu$ explicitly, and you have given explicit expressions for them